# Error when I try to delete a value from a vector of structure based on one of its fields

Tags: c++

I have the following structure:

```
struct Arrays {
            std::string identifier;
            size_t bits;
            int AllocatedSize;
            int CurrentAdress;
            int MaxItemsAdress;
        };
```

And I have a vector that here:

```
std::vector<Arrays> ArrayList;
```

At certain times, I need to remove values from this vector if the "identifier" field of a vector value matches the argument sent to a function of which here is the prototype:

```
void DestroySomeArray(std::vector<std::string> arrays);
```

Except I get this error:

> C2064 The term does not correspond to a function that takes 1
>   arguments

I used std::remove_if with a predicate, here is my entier code:

```
struct Arrays {
            std::string identifier;
            size_t bits;
            int AllocatedSize;
            int CurrentAdress;
            int MaxItemsAdress;
        };
        std::vector<Arrays> ArrayList;
bool IdPredicat(const Arrays &item, std::string id) {
            return (item.identifier == id);
        }
void DestroySomeArray(std::vector<std::string> arrays) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ArrayList.size(); ++i)
                if (IdPredicat(ArrayList[i], arrays[i]))
                    ArrayList.erase(std::remove_if(ArrayList.begin(), ArrayList.end(), IdPredicat(ArrayList[i], arrays[i])), ArrayList.end());
        }
```

I don't understand where the error comes from, and my debugger takes me into the "algorithm" file of the standard libraries. So I couldn't identify the origin of the error (except for the DestroySomeArray function of course).

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why is `arrays` a `std::vector` of `std::string`? Do you want to pass several strings to check for and remove matches for all those strings in `DestroySomeArray`? Maybe [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) will help you understand how to use the erase-remove idiom.

Comment: @super: Yes, that's right thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why your code does not work ? Because you do not send a predicate to the std::remove_if function, you send the result of your predicate, which is a bool, not an unary function (or functor). It explains the error message.

Here's a solution without predicate :

```
void DestroySomeArray(std::vector<std::string> arrays) {
    for (auto it = ArrayList.begin(); it != ArrayList.end();)
        if(std::find(arrays.begin(), arrays.end(), (*it).identifier) != arrays.end())
        { ArrayList.erase(it); }
        else
        { ++it;}
}
```

And with a predicate :

```
struct Pred{
    Pred(std::vector<std::string> arrays) : m_arrays(arrays) {}
    bool operator ()(const Arrays& a) {
        return (std::find(m_arrays.begin(), m_arrays.end(), a.identifier) != m_arrays.end());
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::string> m_arrays;
};

void DestroyWithPredicate(std::vector<std::string> arrays)
{
    auto it = std::remove_if(ArrayList.begin(), ArrayList.end(), Pred(arrays));
    ArrayList.erase(it, ArrayList.end());
}
```

Note that if you directly give a predicate to your Destroy() function, you can write something like that, using different predicates;

```
 Destroy(Predicate1(/* ... */));
 Destroy(Predicate2(/* ... */));
```

Which is quite nice :)

Comment: Okay, I get it now, and it works :) Thank you very much!